# AWS CodePipline gets triggered & deployed all stages from corresponding git branches even commit happens for only one branch

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

**Current CICD implementation**

1. We have three  deployment environments (i.e. AWS LightSail instance)  namely dev, p4d and prod  for each microservice
2. Each deployment environment associated with microservice GIT repo branch i.e. dev branch linked with  dev env , p4d branch linked p4d env and master branch with prod env
3. We have developed  AWS CodePipeline for each  microservice  to manage CICD  deployment pipeline.
4. Current CodePipline Implementation contains with three stages

   Stage 1 - Dev Stage mapped with GIT dev branch , so any changes in dev branch , dev deployment should  be triggered

   Stage 2 - P4D Stage mapped with GIT p4d branch , so any changes in p4d branch , p4d deployment should  be triggered

   Stage 3 - prod Stage mapped with GIT Master  branch , so any changes in master branch , Prod deployment should  be triggered

**Problem**

Whenever we push change code in the git dev branch, CodePipline gets triggered and it deployed all three environments taking the code from respective branches.

**Requirement/Solution**

We want to control the Codepipleline so as to restrict the deployment based on condition.

For example , if the dev branch is changed then Codepipeline will deploy the dev environment, NOT other environments (P4D, Prod).

This way we will be having singe pipeline for each microservice to manage the CICD for three environment

Comment: Are you sure about you have selected branch names correctly on pipelines source section? I have set up the same structure and it is working properly.

Comment: We have tested all branches selected as sources and deployment. It's working. Problem is as mentioned in the problem section i.e. Whenever we push change code in the git dev branch, CodePipline gets triggered and it deploy all THREE environments taking the code from respective branches.  We want to  know how to control this within Codepipeline so that deployment of a specific environment will ONLY take place when changes to that respective branch happened.